# Access Violation when trying to read file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, file-io

I'm trying to read a file based off the MSDN example for using `fopen_s`, but I keep getting an Access Violation error (I've even tried using the regular `fopen` but got the same message. The error points to `err` within my function and I don't see why this is an issue:

```
char* Foo::readFile(const char* filename)
{
    FILE* fp = NULL;
    errno_t err = fopen_s(&fp, filename, "r"); // error points to this line

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    long file_length = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* contents = new char[file_length + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < file_length + 1; i++)
    {
        contents[i] = 0;
    }

    fread(contents, 1, file_length, fp);

    contents[file_length + 1] = '\0';
    if (fp)
        err = fclose(fp);

    return contents;
}
```

And a revised version gives the same error:

```
FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r"); // error again points to this line

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long file_length = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
char* contents = new char[file_length + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < file_length + 1; i++)
{
    contents[i] = 0;
}

fread(contents, 1, file_length, fp);

contents[file_length + 1] = '\0';
fclose(fp);

return contents;
```

My files reside in the **Source Files** as text1.txt and text2.txt. upon calling the function:

```
char* fileData1 = readFile("text1.txt");
char* fileData2 = readFile("text2.txt");
```

Comment: Are you sure `filename` is not NULL?

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you (a) check the validity of `filename`, (`if filename && *filename)` for example) and (b) check the otherwise-useless error-code you are ignoring in `err` after attempting the open. As far as that goes, checking the results of *all* your library calls certainly wouldn't hurt.

Comment: I'll second that comment about checking `filename` for NULL, and also add that `contents[file_length + 1] = '\0';` writes one byte past the end of the allocated block.

Comment: @KenY-N I understand what you are saying, but the program won't let me get that far to even attempt to check. The files themselves do contain data.

Comment: Try this: File *fp = fopen(filename, "r"); assert(fp != NULL);

Comment: @Juniar same results. It just wont get pass fopen... I may have to go a different route on reading.

Comment: That worked for me, I guess you have to try a different route. Try this route: ifstream sin(filename);                                 Just note that whenever you call fopen, fopen_s or any other file reader that is related with C language. You will always get an error on visual studios if not the Access Violation error.

Comment: There seems to be corruption of the filename, at least that is where the error is coming from because it cannot be anywhere else. I would try to copy the whole filename path; i.e C:\\myDocuments\\text1.txt. If you cannot pass this path through the readFile function, then try issuing the same path directly to fopen function; i.e, File *fp = fopen(C:\\myDocuments\\text1.txt, "r");